# How can I fix scripts in /lib/linux-kbuild on Debian 11: pahole-flags.sh not found

Tags: debian, kernel, kernel-modules

I'm currently trying to install netmap, which needs to modify the kernel. However, after installing the kernel headers, I noticed that in `/lib/linux-kbuild-5.10/scripts`, some of the scripts that are expected to be there are missing. This includes `pahole-flags.sh` as well as `mkmakefile` and as a result I get "not found" and "No such file" errors respectively.

I found [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org&q=subject:%22Bug%231027325%5C%3A%20%5C%2Fusr%5C%2Fsrc%5C%2Flinux%5C-headers%5C-5.10.0%5C-20%5C-common%5C%2Fscripts%5C%2Fpahole%5C-flags.sh%5C%3A%20inaccessible%20or%20not%20found%22&o=newest&f=1) recent bug report, stating that this is a regression on stable. It also states, that it has been fixed for a previous version via [this](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/commit/ee29a5e231886d26cef901285bf46a1f929ad4eb) commit. However, all this commit does is modifying the make file.

Is there an easy fix like "just copy the script from repo xy into this directory" or do I need to recompile/upgrade parts of the kernel somehow? I'm not so versatile using linux systems yet, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: **what a direct coincidence!** I got this same problem today, thanks for posting this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The commit you referred to](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/commit/ee29a5e231886d26cef901285bf46a1f929ad4eb) modifies the part of Makefile that is used for building the Debian kernel headers packages (`linux-headers-<kernel version>-<package version>_<arch>.deb`). In other words, it commit makes the `pahole-flags.sh` script be included to the appropriate package in future kernel versions.

Since the kernel configuration & build process does not appear to make any changes to the script, you could just grab the script from the Linux kernel source of the appropriate version (e.g. [here for 5.10 series kernels](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/plain/scripts/pahole-flags.sh?h=v5.10.162)) and place it into your `/lib/linux-kbuild-5.10/scripts` where netmap expects to find it.

The same applies to the `mkmakefile` script ([here for 5.10 series kernels](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/plain/scripts/mkmakefile?h=v5.10.162)).

However, you should be aware that the `mkmakefile`'s functionality that was needed for building the kernel was merged into the main kernel Makefile at about the 5.15 kernel series ([here's the diff](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/diff/?h=v5.15.86&id=2728fcfa4fcc0c4152629c48d49c3bd5f9008329)) and the `mkmakefile` ceased to exist as a separate script. So if netmap still relies on that, it will need to implement the functionality it needs on its own. However, it seems that even in kernel version 5.10, `mkmakefile` just outputs a two-line Makefile, and one of those lines is just a comment, so it should be trivial to replace `mkmakefile`.

Comment: Thanks. I still can't properly install it, but that seems to be another issue unrelated to this question. At least I have the missing scripts now available.